# Probability problem in networking.

Tags: probability

Consider the following statement from *Computer Networking A Top-Down Approach* textbook,

> With packet switching, the probability that a user is active is $0.1$. If there are $35$ users, the probability that there are $11$ or more simultaneously active users is approximately $0.0004$.

$P(11$ or more$) = P(11) + P(12) + \dots + P(35)\\
=1-(P(1) + P(2) + \dots + P(10)) = 1.1111111111111119\times 10^{-11$}$

Something is wrong with my thinking, can someone point it out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let random variable $X$ be the number of actives. Then if we use your procedure, we want
$$1-\left(\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\cdots+\Pr(X=10)\right).\tag{1}$$
Note this is a little different from yours, you had left out the possibility $X=0$.

That correction, however, does not account for the error, so you must have computed the probabilities incorrectly.  Note that 
$$\Pr(X=k)=\binom{35}{k}(0.1)^k (0.9)^{35-k}.$$
We have to be *very very* careful in the computation. The sum we are computing in (1) is very close to $1$, so roundoff error can be catastrophic.

**Another way:** I can see why you wanted to use (1), it looks like a shorter computation. However, in this situation, it is better to compute 
$$\Pr(X=11)+\Pr(X=12)+\cdots+\Pr(X=35)\tag{2}$$
directly.

That's because the mean number of actives is $3.5$, so the first number in the sum (2) is small, and pretty quickly we are adding virtually nothing, so we can truncate the computation early. Also, the computation via (2) is **numerically stable**, while using (1) definitely is not.

**Remarks:** $1.$ Nowadays, many programs, and even some calculators, will compute binomial probabilities and their sums. Wolfram Alpha (free) will do it.

$2.$ If you want to use an approximate procedure, I would recommend the *Poisson* approximation. So the required probability is not far from
$$\sum_{11}^{35} e^{-3.5} \frac{(3.5)^n}{n!}.$$
Only the first few terms really matter.

Answer (score 3):

It might be how you computed $P(n)$. It should be $$P(n)= \binom{35}{n} 0.1^n 0.9^{35-n}.$$

[Here is the computation in WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-+sum+%5B%2835+choose+n%29+.1%5En+.9%5E%2835-n%29%5D+from+n%3D0+to+10).

Comment: right, forgot about bernoulli trials.

Answer (score 0):

Your random variable follows the binomial distribution $\mathcal{B}(35,0.1)$.

The probability you are asking for is:

$P(X\ge 11)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=11}^{35}\binom{35}{n}\cdot0.1^n\cdot (1-0.1)^{35-n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of users $X$ that are active is Binomial(35, 0.1). So, P(k) = (35 choose k) p^k*(1-p)^(35-k). The summation that you have is hard to compute because you have to be careful in computing (n choose k). A better way is to use a normal approximation to Binomial random variable. We know $\mu = E[X] = 3.5$ and $\sigma^2 = Var[X] = 35*0.1*0.9$.
\begin{split}
P(X \geq 11) 
&= 
P\left( (X-\mu)/\sigma \geq (11 - 3.5)/\sigma \right)
\\
&=
\Phi(-(11 - 3.5)/\sigma),
\end{split}
where $\Phi$ is CDF of normal distribution. I got this answer to be 1.191e-05